# How to change the sqlite table structure dynamically in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uitextfield

I'm developing an iPad application, in which i have to store some data in the database. So that, i prefer to use SQLite, here i have an doubt regarding the table structure. Let me explain, actually there is a view in which, the user can add the labor Qty, labor type and so on, at default i have displayed only one set of fields.

[image: This is how it looks like]

I have created table with the five fields ( Labor Qty, Labor Type.....) and it works fine. Now i need to setup a button  "Add New" at the bottom, i apologize for the low resolution image, when the user click on the button, will generate another five fields below the previous. So how can i get the text fields values into the database table since i have created only for five fields. I tried and googled it but can't find the correct way. Any Help Appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you question is little unclear.. you want to add more rows based on add new click or you want to add more collum on click of that button?

Comment: @DeveloperJigarPandya i want to add rows with the button click.

Answer (score 0):

Well in that case what you can do is following.

1. put your content in UIScrollView
2. Have the textboxes in UIWebView and upon click on add new create new instance of that.
3. Put the X,Y co-ordinate in increasing manner let's say first time it is at 10,50 second time 40,50 third time 70,50 and so on,,
4. also increase X,Y co-ordinates of the button itself.

This way you can achieve above.

Using above logic you can get something like following.[image]

Comment: I assume that you are talking about subviews, (i.e) having web view inside the uiscrollview. Am i right ?

Comment: k, if it so how can i insert the added field values inside the sqlite table. Kindly let me know.

Comment: you can check http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/10/sqlite-tutorial-loading-data-as.html for this one.

Comment: i have gone through the link which u have send, let me explain what i need, i have created the database with five fields (labor qty,labor type, cost and so on..) after entering the values and click on save it will be saved also it working fine for me. Adding the rows consists of another five fields for which i haven't create in a database so how can i perform this.